# Why do the standard errors obtained via lsqcurvefit and fminunc function differ?

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval, non-linear-regression, hessian-matrix, uncertainty

I am fitting a model to experimental data in Matlab. For this model I wanted to find the parameters by minimising the sum of square residues between the experimental and model data set. The model is of the form shown below:

G(x) = G0/(1+(x/x_c)^(2m))

where G0, x_c and m are the parameters to be optimised.

To identify the parameters I have used both lsqcurvefit and fminunc tool on Matlab. For lsqcurvefit I use the output jacobian matrix with the nlparci tool to dermine 95% confidence interval and back track to calculate the standard errors as shown below.

```
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian] = lsqcurvefit(___)
ci = nlparci(x,residual,'Jacobian',J);    %Returns 95% confidence interval
err = ((ci(:,2)-ci(:,1))./3.92);          %Standard error
```

I then calculated the standard error using fminunc function by minimising the sum of square residues. A hessian matrix can be obtained through this process. The hessian matrix was used to determine the standard error as shown below:

```
err = sqrt(diag(inv(Hessian)));           %Standard error
```

The issue is that the standard errors which I obtain from lsqcurvefit and fminunc differ. I assumed that there will be slight variations in the standard errors in the different approaches but I am getting errors which are much larger when I use fminunc. The optimised parameters obtained using the individual tools are the same though.

Why is the error much larger when using fminunc? Am I using the correct methods to compute the errors?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. So what was your assumption? That using different approaches will result in the exact same estimates? Why should be this the case?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I assumed that there will be slight variations in the standard errors in the different approached but I am getting errors which are much larger when I use fminunc. The optimised parameters obtained using the individual tools are the same though. I am not sure if I am using the correct methods to compute the errors.